# What is a simple example of bound state in the continuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, quantum-states

I am curious about the concept of bound state in the continuum. What is a simple example Hamiltonian which have this property and how can I derive this particular bound state?

What are the properties of this state?

Comment: The hydrogen atom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom

Comment: In the hydrogen atom the bound states have negative energy while the scattering states (the continuum) have positive energies. These two regions of the spectrum seem separated.

Comment: Ah, i understand. You want a system where the point spectrum is in the continuous spectrum.

Comment: I think this is the definition of a bound state in the continuum. But I am not an expert and I was only curious about that.